# Get USER SID in a Service

Tags: delphi, service, sid

I need to read a software license that is stored in a Registry key located under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

I'm running in a service in the SYSTEM account, so I cannot read this key.

I discovered that this Registry key has an account in HKEY_USER, where I can read the information. But I need to find out the SID of the logged in user.

How do I find this from a service in Delphi?

Comment: Why not impersonate the user calling the service and read the registry key?

Comment: Which logged in user? There may be several. Or none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [LookupAccountName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the SID belonging to a given username (and the domain it belongs to). [ConvertSidToStringSid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used to convert the SID to a String.

Alternatively use the [Delphi Jedi Windows Security Code Library](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/) (JWSCL).

Comment: You can use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` to discover logged in sessions, and `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` to retrieve the username + domain of those sessions, and then call `LookupAccountName()`. Another option is to enumerate running processes until you discover one (usually Explorer) running in the desired session, then open a handle to the process, grab its process token, and query it for its logon SID.

Comment: Please, how use LookupAccountName. O name user active, find function JEDI Library "GetInteractiveUserName".